# gazebo_ros_control plugin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [/robot_description] on the ROS param server

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi guys,
trying to simulate a kuka iiwa in gazebo11 with Ubuntu 20 and ROS noetic. I get the following output after I

```
roslaunch iiwa_gazebo iiwa.launch
```

[image: output]

So it never loads the gazebo_ros plugin. I can't figure out why.
These are the contents of the log file:

[image: log file]

I have attached the
launch file [C:\fakepath\iiwa.launch](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/16479035139849192.launch) and
sdf file [C:\fakepath\iiwa7_no_collision.sdf](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/16479035339511737.sdf)

If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated :)
Thank you guys so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27970/gazebo_ros_control-plugin-is-waiting-for-model-urdf-in-parameter-%5B/robot_description%5D-on-the-ros-param-server/) by [weirdcookie](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/78817/weirdcookie/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

matching

```
<param name
```

in the launch file with the

```
<robotParam>
```

in the .sdf worked! hehe :)

---

Originally posted by [weirdcookie](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/78817/weirdcookie/) with karma: 1 on 2022-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0